# How to load Results from a different method into a variable using C#

Tags: c#, variables, main-method

My Main Method is calling another method(SqlConnector) which is fetching results from SQL database. I need load the results from SqlConnector Method into a variable called "ID".

Nothing happens when i execute this. I don't think my SqlConnector Method is getting invoked.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string SyncType = args[0];
    try
    {
        if (SyncType == "Compute")
        {
            string InitialSQLStatement = ($"exec StartUsage '{SyncType}'");
            var ID = SqlConnector(InitialSQLStatement);

            int RowID = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
            Console.WriteLine($"{ID},{RowID}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            ...Calling a different Class in case of Compute
            Compute Compute = new Compute();
            var task = Compute.GetBaseDetails(RowID);
            task.Wait();
        }

        else if (SyncType == "Blob")
        {
            ...Calling a different Class in case of Blob
        }

        else if (SyncType == "FileShare")
        {
            ...Calling a different Class in case of FileShare
        }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

public static SqlDataReader SqlConnector(string SQLStatement)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerName;
    builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdmin;
    builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdminPasword;
    builder.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLStatement, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader Executed = command.ExecuteReader();

            connection.Close();
            return Executed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when call Convert.ToInt32(ID), while ID is an object of type SqlDataReader? It seems rather meaningless.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to C#.
The SQL Connector Method will return a single numeric digit (0-800). 
So I thought of convert the variable ID to Int32. 

But that is not the actual problem. My issue is, how to get the result from SQLConnector Method into my Main Method variable ID,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Problem is, that you cannot convert the SqlReader to an Integer. You have to read first, then Convert the string to an integer. I didn't test the code, but this should work.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string SyncType = args[0];
        try
        {
            if (SyncType == "Compute")
            {
                string InitialSQLStatement = ($"exec StartUsage '{SyncType}'");
                int RowID = ConnectAndReadID(InitialSQLStatement);
                Console.WriteLine($"{RowID}");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                //...Calling a different Class in case of Compute
                Compute Compute = new Compute();
                var task = Compute.GetBaseDetails(RowID);
                task.Wait();
            }

            else if (SyncType == "Blob")
            {
                //...Calling a different Class in case of Blob
            }

            else if (SyncType == "FileShare")
            {
                //...Calling a different Class in case of FileShare
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static int ConnectAndReadID(string SQLStatement)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerName;
        builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdmin;
        builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdminPasword;
        builder.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLStatement, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string str = reader.GetString(0); // Read first column
                    connection.Close();
                    return Convert.ToInt32(str);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Your query fails
                    connection.Close();
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<int> ConnectAndReadIDs(string SQLStatement)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerName;
        builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdmin;
        builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServerAdminPasword;
        builder.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseName;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLStatement, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<int> Ids = new List<int>(); // Create a List since you have multiple ids
                while (reader.Read()) // Instead of checking once if the reader has data, read rows until it doesnt have data anymore
                {
                    string str = reader.GetString(0); // Read first column
                    Ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(str)); // Add the value to the Ids List
                }
                connection.Close();
                return Ids; // Return all Ids
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul. I'm able to return single row.
What should my code look like If I would like to return all records?

Comment: I Updated my answer. The Method I added returns all Ids it reads from your SQL Query.